# How can i change the background color of text in cells, instead of the background color of the cells themselves?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a standard MS-word table. When I created the table, I had some text with a background color marked, and now every cell has this as default. I am not talking about the full cell background color, but the one who only works as a marker on the text, but is still changed through the paint bucket.

I can't figure out how to remove the background color from my table now.

1. If I mark multiple cells, and change the paintbucket background color, the full cells' color changes, but not the text's background color.
2. If I mark the full text of a single cell, the same happens
3. If I mark a cell's partial text, it actually works, but this is way to time consuming.
4. Using the highlighter tool does nothing at all, the text's background color is dominant.

Is there a way of marking all of my cells, and changing the background color of the texts, and not the background color of the cells?

Comment: I am not able to replicate the problem you are describing. What version of Word are you using? When you created the table, did you type in the text or paste it from another source?

Comment: I marked the text, which was several separate words with linebreaks inbetween them, and clicked insert table from the menu. I couldn't choose the number of rows or columns though, so I had to add afterwards. It's the one from Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010.

Comment: Same version I am using. Try opening a new document, add a simple table and some text. Then see if you can highlight the text the color you wish. If you can, then there is something wrong with the table in the original document. If you can not, then something is wrong with Word. In the case of the latter, conduct a repair of the installation from the control panel.

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to remove the text background color by selecting the text and changing the Style to Normal. It's the first icon on the left on the Styles group on Home tab.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not working... I tried this. Which version of Word are u using?

Comment: Word 2007 (to hit 10 chars)

Answer (score 0):

I selected the whole table, right-clicked, and there was a "Clear Formatting" button as part of the palette that popped.

Clearing worked for me. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this is a problem also in Office 365.

Clearing the formatting of the text works, but in my case the background color of the text comes from a style, and I need that style unchanged while locally overriding the color. So completely wiping the formatting is not an option.

A workaround could be to copy the text out of the table, change the appearance of the text, then copy it back to the table. Obviously not a good option for a large table.

Comment: You are not providing a clear answer, you are at best making a comment. In instances like this, when you don't have a clear answer to provide, you should not use answer function.