# Inserting row in Word table leaves blank space

Tags: microsoft-word

Ok I'll admit I know little to nothing about using Word for anything more than typing something up but how do I get rid of this blank space in my table after I insert a new row???

[image: highlighted word row]

Comment: Related [1](https://superuser.com/q/959577/152004), [2](https://superuser.com/q/1328097/152004)

Comment: probably a formatation error. Try to show the paragraph characters, and see if there is a difference in formatation. also, try to copy the format from one row to the other (usually, the format of a new row corresponds to the row ABOVE, not below). If that doesn't work, post an example word file. From your scrrenshot it could be many things.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to adjust the height of the table cells appropriately.
To insert a new row more conveniently, you could place the cursor at the end of the cell row and press Enter.
For more information: [Add a cell, row, or column to a table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-cell-row-or-column-to-a-table-b030ef77-f219-4998-868b-ba85534867f1)
[image]